# Python, how to get mro of function object explicitly?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def num():
    return 6


print(type(num).mro())
print(type(num))
print(function.mro())

// output is as follows:
[<class 'function'>, <class 'object'>]
<class 'function'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(function.mro())
      ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

Why is this happening ? I mean int.mro(), dict.mro(), ..etc are working fine. Then why is it not working on function type ?

trying to understand python. expecting explanation.

Comment: What `function` type are you refering to? The error tells you there is no such type defined in your code

Comment: @UnholySheep i thought functions are objects and defined in python like "class function(object):". So i wanted to get mro of this function class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, everything is an object, including classes, functions, and primitive data types. The `mro` method stands for Method Resolution Order, and it's available on class objects to determine the order in which base classes are considered when looking up a method. This is especially useful for understanding multiple inheritance.

1. `print(type(num).mro())`:

   - `num` is a function.
   - `type(num)` returns the type of `num`, which is `<class 'function'>`.
   - `type(num).mro()` will give the method resolution order for the function class, which is `[<class 'function'>, <class 'object'>]`.
2. `print(type(num))`:

   - This is just printing the type of the `num` function, which is `<class 'function'>`.
3. `print(function.mro())`:

   - Here, you're trying to access the `mro` method of something named `function`, but there's no such built-in name in Python. That's why you're getting a `NameError`.

The confusion might be stemming from how you're trying to access the `mro` for functions. For classes like `int` and `dict`, you can directly call `int.mro()` and `dict.mro()`, respectively, because `int` and `dict` are both class objects themselves. However, there's no built-in `function` class in Python you can directly reference.

If you wanted to see the MRO for functions, you'd do it the way you did with your `num` function:

```py
def some_function():
    pass

print(type(some_function).mro())
```

Or more directly:

```py
print((lambda: None).__class__.mro())
```

Both of these would give you the method resolution order for a function.